# Inputting two word string from a file (C++)

Tags: c++, string, file, input, fstream

I have a .txt file in which I have to read in multiple items and
then output them in a console. Here's a sample of a line from the text file

> int - string - int - float - float - string - char*
>
> 32073 Stationary Bike 60 135 490.9 moderate Tue Apr 17 16:53:46

<s>My issue here is mainly getting the second item, the string, to be input despite the space between the two words. It's also worth noting sometimes the string there is only one word. Right now it seems like choiceName is taking the entire line without stopping at a space like I thought it would.</s>

I'm only getting a single line from the text file at a time outputted to the console instead of everything in the file. I need to hit enter to get the next line which I don't want,

```
    while(!(transactionLog >> idNum).eof())
    {
        getline(transactionLog, choiceName, ',');
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');

        transactionLog >> minutes >> weightPoundsCopy >> calories >> intensity;
        getline(transactionLog, timeStamp, '\n');

        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(5) << idNum << choiceName << " " << minutes << " " << weightPoundsCopy << " " << calories << " " << intensity << " " << timeStamp << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Consider using regex?

Comment: "It's also worth noting sometimes the string there is only one word." - then you need to use a  delimiter other than a space, such as a comma.

Comment: How do you store char pointer in the txt file?

Comment: @KillzoneKid The code involving the last portion of the line (the time) was provided by a professor. I haven't learned about char pointers yet.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can't believe I didn't think of that. That fixed that part at least. Thank you.

Comment: It is tricky: read two words with the extraction operator then concatenate them. `in >> str1 >> str2`.

Comment: To delimit fields, I would not use `,` (comma), it is too common in real text. I would use `\t` (tab), `|`, or other printable character that is less likely to appear in real text. Or better, I would use a non-printable character, like `\x01`.

Comment: The question and the code is mostly incomprehensible. Nothing is mentioned about any commas anywhere, yet a portion of the code, inexplicably attempts to gobble up input to the next comma. Additionally the code is a random mixture of formatted input extraction operators, `>>`, and `std::getline`(). Mixing `>>` together with `getline` is always a recipe for failure, due to their very subtle interactions. You need to figure out what your file format is, and then either always use `>>`, or use `getline()` to read one line at a time. Period. Any other approach will lead only to pain and suffering.

Comment: If you really can't change the format and it really does have variable numbers of words *in one field only* then you can solve it. I've had to do it. Read in a whole line. Then work your way *backwards* using `string::find_last_of` and copy your fields into the structure you want. Once you have taken them all off the end, take off the front ones, then what's left is your variable sized field.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've figured out that part of my question since posting thanks to another comment hence crossing it out. I've also updated the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is stuck waiting for Enter because you use `std::cin` instead of `transactionLog`.